# Trying to install Fedora 20 as a Oracle Virtual Box VM ; Installer launches to black screen

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, fedora

I'm trying to install Fedora 20 as a Oracle VM Virtual Box; shortly after the installer launches it just goes to a black screen. My machine is running Windows 7 and the Virtual Box install is the latest. Any thoughts on this problem?

Comment: Check the checksum on the Fedora ISO.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Still trying to figure it out. Install media is fine, downloaded several times. System will start and I can select the install option from the initial screen, then goes to a white screen and appears to lock.

Comment: As a note, I occasionally get "[    0.000000] tsc: Fast calibration failed" highlighted in black on the white background.

Comment: The Fast caliberation failed error is super common. I have it on my physical install and my centos VMs with no real issues